# How to share a cookie between diffrent domains?

Tags: cookies, coldfusion, session-cookies

I have one Admin website (Example: http://www.admin.web.com/control/) and Public websites like (http://example.web.com and http://example.com)

I want to create one cookie from http://www.admin.web.com/control/ which will be shared to both website http://www.example.web.com and http://www.example.com.

Here both public websites are the same with different URLs

So to share cookie I am creating domain specific cookie

```
<cfcookie name="admin" value="xyz" domain=".web.com">
```

So above cookie which will be created from http://admin.web.com will be shared with http://example.web.com but not with http://example.com.

Can any one tell me how I will share same cookie for http://example.com?

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is that you can't.  As far as the users browsers are concerned admin.web.com and example.web.com are subdomains of the same (web.com) domain so they could be owned by the same person.  This means you can set it up so that the sharing you've seen above works.
Unfortunately as you've seen example.com doesn't share a domain so you can't share them as domain cookies.

There are a couple of ways to get round this that I can think of off the top of my head, none of which are particularly nice:

- You could probably get away with using an ajax callstraight to example.web.com from example.com with the contents of the cookie in the response to the page.
- You could use an iframe in the example.com pages that points to the example.web.com page and then send the details from the read cookie back setting the same cookie then on example.com.

For sensible security reasons it's not really a good idea to do either but instead to look for the reason you're trying to share information across domains and try and figure out a way of avoiding it.

Comment: I knew that It's not possible.
Thanks Benny for suggestion but solution doesn't suits my app.

Comment: Why not encrypt the cookie with a private key and send it over? gpg, gnu, etc. etc.